# How does this SQL query work?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(LTRIM(RTRIM('!! ATHEN !!','!'), '!'), 'AN', '**'),'*','TROUBLE') FROM DUAL;
```

I'm confused about above question how this query works ?

Comment: i don't know that's why i asked this question

Comment: You could try to run it, or put some line breaks and indenting into it. Just as programming code, queries are allowed to have whitespace too. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(
    TRANSLATE(
      LTRIM(
        RTRIM('!! ATHEN !!','!')
        , '!')
      , 'AN'
      , '**')
    ,'*'
    ,'TROUBLE')
FROM DUAL;
```

It doesn't work on MySQL.

It would return a single constant value. DUAL is a system table with one record. It allows you to select a constant value when you don't actually have a table to query from, because dual is always there. `FROM DUAL` is optional in MySQL and in Oracle from 23c on.

What this query should do:

- It takes the text '!! ATHEN !!'
- It trims the '!' on both ends (ltrim and rtrim)
- It 'translates' A and N to `*` and `*`.
- It replaces each `*` with 'TROUBLE'

So I'd expect the output to be something like ' TROUBLETHETROUBLE '.

That is, when you run it on Oracle. MySQL won't accept the second parameter in RTRIM as Nanne pointed out in the comments.

Comment: The funny thing is that "RTRIM" doesn't take 2 parameters in MYSQL as far as I know. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim

Comment: translate() is not a MySQL function either as far as I know

Comment: The output is indeed `' TROUBLETHETROUBLE '`.